# Background gradient in border?

Tags: css, border, gradient, shapes

I am trying to set a background gradient to the border-top, but I don't want this to affect my other borders. Since I am using borders to create a triangle shape, the other border must be transparent.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gno5295u/

[image]

```
<div id="logo">
    <div id="left-s"></div>
    <div id="right-s"></div>
</div>

#logo {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background: #000000;
    display: block;
}
#left-s {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 75px;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    border-top: 100px solid red;
    border-right: 100px solid transparent;
}
#right-s {
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    left: 25px;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    border-bottom: 100px solid red;
    border-left: 100px solid transparent;
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Please add more details.

Comment: If you open the fiddle, you can see two red divs, those are square divs, but visible is only a triangle. I am trying to set that red to a gradient, without affecting the transparent border.

Comment: Can you draw the final result if you can  not explain please?

Comment: It's not possible to add a gradient to border. You'll need `svg` here.

Comment: It is possible to add a gradient to a border, as I have seen that many times on the internet. But I dont know how to do this when having a transparent border which may not be affected.

Comment: You should checkout this image, http://i.imgur.com/OKwmTcX.png

Comment: @Joost Meijer thank you for adding the image can you provide the grandien too?

Comment: linear-gradient(red, blue);

Comment: @Tambo, just that red to blue gradient. It doesnt really matter, I can always change it whatever I like.

Comment: this is a bit hacky but http://jsfiddle.net/gno5295u/2/

Comment: Can you explain how you did that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an `svg` equivalent with `linearGradient` instead of a single color.

```html
<svg width="200" height="200">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="gradient" x1="0" y1="0" x2="100%" y2="0">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="red" stop-opacity="1" />
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="yellow" stop-opacity="1" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <path d="M0,0 L200,0 L200,200 L 0,200z" />
  <path d="M75,20 h100 l-100,100" fill="url(#gradient)" />
  <path d="M125,80 v100 h-100z" fill="url(#gradient)" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

i have added background-gradient for the div and added pseudo element to hide the extra space

```css
#logo {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #000000;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
#left-s {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 45px;
  right: 70px;
}
#right-s {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  overflow: hidden;
  bottom: 45px;
  left: 70px;
}
#left-s:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150%;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 50, 50, 1) 1%, rgba(125, 185, 232, 1) 100%);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: top right;
}
#right-s:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150%;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 50, 50, 1) 1%, rgba(125, 185, 232, 1) 100%);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: top left;
  left: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div id="logo">
  <div id="left-s"></div>
  <div id="right-s"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am sorry, you helped me very well. But that was not the answer that really helped me out. Thank you though.